# Solution of Problem 22 in section 4 in chapter 12 of Royden "real analysis third edition "

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Here is the question :

Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}, \lambda)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Suppose that $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mu-$integrable function and that $h: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $\lambda-$integrable function. Define $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y).$ Prove that $f$ is $\mu \times \lambda$ integrable and that $$\int_{X\times Y} f d(\mu \times \lambda) = (\int_{X}g d\mu) (\int_{Y} hd\lambda).$$

And here is its solution:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- Why $\chi_{A}.\chi_{B} = \chi_{A \times B} $?

2-why $f = \chi_{A \times B}$ leads to that $f$ is integrable?which theorem said this?

3-Why $f^{-}$ looks like this?

Could anyone explain this for me please? 
 is there a proof for this? and also $f^+$ 
**EDIT:**

This question is also problem 10 on pg.423 in Royden "real analysis fourth edition" and I prefer an answer depending on this edition of Royden

Comment: You need to think about this on your own at least a little. If you write out both sides of the equation in point $1$ it is obvious. For point $2$ the authors have forgotten to ask that $A$ and $B$ have finite measure (well they have not forgotten, it follows from $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$ being integrable).  For point number $3$ remember that positive times positive is positive, same with negative times negative, while negative times positive is negative ...

Comment: @s.harp does not $X,Y$ being $\sigma-$ finite implies that $A,B$ have finite measures?

Comment: @Emptymind No, you are confusing finite and $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: So how can we solve this problem? @s.harp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\chi_A \cdot \chi_B = \chi_{A \times B}$: 
   writing down the definitions we have $$\chi_A (x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{for } x \in A \\ 0 & \text{for } x \in X \setminus A \end{cases}$$ and analogously for $\chi_B (y)$ for $y \in Y$. Therefore, if $\chi_{A} (x) \cdot \chi_{B} (y) = 1$, then $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. The other way round, if $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, we have $\chi_A (x) \cdot \chi_B (y) =1$. But that means, by the definition of $\chi_{A \times B} (x,y)$, that $\chi_A (x) \cdot \chi_B(y) = \chi_{A \times B} (x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in X\times Y$.
2. The integrability of $f = \chi_{A \times B}$ follows from the equation$$\int f ~ \mathrm{d} (\mu \times \nu) = \mu (A) \cdot \nu(B)$$which is shown in the text. The right hand side is $< \infty$ because $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$ are integrable by assumption.
3. For $f^-$ look at the definition of it: $$f^- = - f \cdot \chi_{\{f < 0\}} = - g \cdot h \chi_{\{g\cdot h <0\}} = -g \cdot h \big( \chi_{\{g > 0 , h < 0\}} + \chi_{\{g <0 , h >0\}} \big) = -h \chi_{\{h < 0\}} \cdot g \chi_{\{g >0\}} + -g \chi_{\{g<0\}} \cdot h \chi_{\{h >0\}} = h^- g^+ + g^- h^+.$$
   Here I freely used the equations $\chi_A \cdot \chi_{B} = \chi_{A \cap B}$ and $\chi_A + \chi_B = \chi_{A \cup B}$. Think about why these hold. That is similar to 1.

Comment: And how does the result hold for simple functions .... do you have details?

Comment: yes I do. But answer these questions: what is a simple function? What do we have to show such that the desired result holds for a simple function? What did the authors show up to line three in your screenshot and how can we use this? Maybe we can work our way to the solution together.